# How can I create a posts slider for my Wordpress blog like the products slider on theverge.com

Tags: jquery, slider, wordpress

I would like to show all the blog posts on my [Wordpress blog](http://fuenfbuecher.de) (German) in a horizontal slider similar to the "products" slider on [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/) (half way down the homepage). My blog is based on the Thesis Theme.

For each post I defined a thumbnail image and a short title of the post as a custom field.

I found various Plugins such as "WP Featured Content Slider" or the "WP Coda Slider", but none of them are close to the slider I am looking for. Something that looked very promising was the "Moving Boxes" jQuery slider, but due to my limited knowledge about jQuery (and Javascript) I didn't manage to make it work.

Does anyone know how to build such a slider? Or are there plugins or tools available that I didn't come across yet?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Philippe I can help you.

You need to create two loops, one to handle the main content for the sliderview, and the other to populate the thumbnails to correspond to the relative posts.

This example is loose but you can find better ones online - Mind you, you are going to want to use the `$wp_query` function so you can get a more accurate post listing

I strongly recommend using [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle)

```
<!-- loop for slider -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="slider">
<!-- format your posts-->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<!-- loop for thumbnails -->

<div class="nav">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- format your thumbnails -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>


// then call your slideshow

$('#slider').after('<ul id="nav">').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '#nav', 

    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
    } 
});
```